# Constructing the $Z_2 \times Z_2$ group table

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, direct-product, cayley-table

In A. Zee's group theory book p. 47-49, he constructs the group table with four elements $\{I,A,B,C\}$

$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& I & A & B & C \\ 
\hline
I & I & A & B & C \\ 
A & A \\ 
B & B \\ 
C & C
\end{array}$

There are two possibilities for the second row second column, $A^2 = I$ or $A^2 = B$ (it could also be $~A^2 = C~$ but your $~C~$ is my $B~$).

For $A^2 = B$, it corresponds to the $Z_4$ group, and the construction of the group table is clear,

$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& I & A & B & C \\ 
\hline
I & I & A & B & C \\ 
A & A & B & C & I \\ 
B & B & C & I & A \\ 
C & C & I & A & B
\end{array}$

For $A^2 = I$, the second row and second column is a consequence of the "once and only once rule" of the group table,

$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& I & A & B & C \\ 
\hline
I & I & A & B & C \\ 
A & A & I & C & B \\ 
B & B & C \\ 
C & C & B 
\end{array}$

Now, the lower right part of the table has two possibilities

$\begin{array}{c|c}
I & A \\ 
\hline
A & I
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{c|c}
A & I \\ 
\hline
I & A
\end{array}$

Zee's says that these two amount to the same thing, you just rename $B$ and $C$, which when you check the group composition, either one is consistent so that we have,

$\begin{array}{c|cccc}
& I & A & B & C \\ 
\hline
I & I & A & B & C \\ 
A & A & I & C & B \\ 
B & B & C & I & A \\ 
C & C & B & A & I
\end{array}$

but what does the statement "these two amount to the same thing, you just rename $B$ and $C$" really mean? I need more exposition to understand more what is the argument (BTW, this is the $Z_2 \times Z_2$ group ).

---

There is another question, we can construct the $Z_2 \times Z_2$ group table through the cyclic subgroups,

If $~A^4 = I~$ then the group is $Z_4$. By Lagrange's theorem, $~A^3 = I~$ is not possible since a group with order four cannot have a subgroup of order three. If $A^2 = I$ then we multiply $B$ by itself, either $B^2 = I$ or $B^4 = I$. The latter is ruled out so we have $B^2 = I$ and $AB = BA = C$.

I need some clarifications on why,

1. We multiply $B$ by itself. Is it because $A$, $A^2$ is already cyclic so that we test if it is consistent if $B$ is also a cyclic subgroup? Is it really necessary that all subgroups must be cyclic if one of it is cyclic?
2. $B^4 = I$ is ruled out. I cannot find the argument on why this must be the case. I know I need to do some group element multiplication and find a contradiction but so far I cannot find any.

Comment: You already said "your $~C~$ is my $B~$" in the first part, so you're aware of what's going on here. "these two amount to the same thing" is noting the exact same naming freedom, just using different words.

Comment: The two choices for the lower right quadrant do *not* amount to the same thing.  The first choice results in the non-cyclic group which you call $Z_2 \otimes Z_2$ (I would call it $C_2 \times C_2$).  The second one results in a cyclic group.  You can match it with your $Z_4$ table by relabeling $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Is it common to use $\otimes$ for the direct product? This is terribly confusing, given that $\otimes$ already has a(n extremely important, distinct) meaning in the world of abelian groups.

Comment: In the version of Zee's book that's [available through Google](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Group_Theory_in_a_Nutshell_for_Physicist/heOoCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover), it does not say that the two choices for the $2\times2$ block in the lower right "amount to the same thing". That makes me wonder, was the book was revised?

Comment: The passage from Zee that you quote in the second part of your question (which *does* match what one finds on Google Books), seems very sloppy. Ravi Fernando points out the problem with the way he seems to be using $A^4=I$ to mean $A$ has order $4$. I think he multiplies $B$ by itself, not as a consistency check, but because he has already exhausted the powers of $A$ and still has group elements left, which are not powers of $A$, that need to be understood.

Comment: It is wrong that $B^4=I$ is ruled out. Actually it is always true. But taking it the way he means it, as $B$ has order $4$, it could be that $B^2=A$ and then $B$ would have order $4$. It's possible he means that $B$ having order $4$ is ruled out because that's just like $A$ having order $4$ (using the arbitrariness of names of elements), and that's a case that he already dealt with. If that's what he meant, it would have been nice if he had said so explicitly.

Comment: Don't use $\otimes$ for the cartesian product! $\otimes$ has an existing meaning for abelian groups and with the usual meaning $\mathbb{Z}_2 \otimes \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: @Arthur I have checked it again, and it seems like renaming $B$ and $C$ will not show that they are the same thing, as Ravi Fernando said.

Comment: @RaviFernando Indeed, I have checked it again, they are not the same!

Comment: @BrianShin That is what Zee used, although I am not aware of what you are pertaining.

Comment: @WillOrrick In my pdf copy of Zee's book, that is what he said, but by checking the link you gave it is indeed different! Oh my, I am not aware of a difference in printing versions, I should check my hardcopy later.
In the second part of my question, it is really unclear what he exactly means but by taking what you are saying it kinda makes more sense but this must be clarified to avoid other people having the same confusion.

Comment: @WillOrrick Can you clarify what you mean by saying, "as $B$ has order $4$, it could be that $B^2 = A$ and then $B$ would have order $4$", yes $B^4 = I$ implies $B^2 = A$, but then what?

Comment: What I meant was this: Zee says $B^4=I$ is ruled out (in the case where $A$ has order $2$). This is wrong since $g^4=I$ for every $g$ in any group with four elements. Even if we interpret "$B^4=I$ is ruled out" as "$B$ having order 4 is ruled out", it is still wrong. In the group with elements $I$, $B$, $B^2=A$, and $B^3=C=B^{-1}$, the element $B$ has order $4$ (as does the element $B^{-1}$). Notice that $A$ has order $2$ in this group. So $A$ having order $2$ does not rule out $B$ having order $4$. I think Zee is simply wrong here.

Comment: In reference to the comments of Brian Shin and Qiaochu Yuan, mathematicians use the symbol "$\otimes$" for the [tensor product](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2007/04/06/tensor-products-of-abelian-groups/); the symbol "$\times$" is used for the direct product, which is the product being used here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two choices for the lower right quadrant do *not* amount to the same thing.  The first choice results in the non-cyclic group which you call $Z_2 \otimes Z_2$ (I would call it $C_2 \times C_2$).  The second one results in a cyclic group ($Z_4$, or $C_4$).  You can match it with your $Z_4$ table by relabeling $A$ and $B$.  (As Arthur pointed out in the comments, you did a similar relabeling earlier when you said "your $C$ is my $B$".)  You can tell that these groups are really different because the first has the property that every element squares to $I$, and the second doesn't.

As for the second half of your question, let me first point out that it's not actually true that if $A^4 = I$, then the group is cyclic.  In fact, even in the non-cyclic group, you also have $A^4 = I$; it's just that $A^2 = I$ too.  What you mean to say is that if $A$ has *order* 4, then the group is cyclic. (In case you haven't seen this term yet, the *order* of $A$ is defined as the smallest $n > 0$ with the property that $A^n = I$.)

Now let me try to clarify how to do the classification in terms of cyclic subgroups.  As you said, Lagrange's theorem implies that every element has order 1, 2, or 4.  (And of course only the identity, $I$, has order 1.)  If there is *any* element with order 4, then that makes the group cyclic.  (It could be $A$, $B$, or $C$--and in fact it will be two out of those three--but as before you can rename elements so that $A$ is one of them.)  If there is no element with order 4, then everything but $I$ must have order 2.  This means that you have all $I$'s along the diagonal of your multiplication table.  Given this, you can fill in the rest of the table using the "once and only once rule" that you mentioned.  This proves that every group of order 4 is either $C_4$ or $C_2 \times C_2$.

Comment: I understand that the correct statement is that given a group with four elements and if there exists an element with order $4$ then the group is cyclic. What is not clear to me is when you said that given $A^4 = I$ it does not always imply that the group is cyclic, can you give an example? Also, what do you mean by "it's just that $A^2 = I$ too" in reference to the sentence before it?

Comment: In your third paragraph, you said that if there is any element with order $4$ then that makes the group cyclic and that element could be $A$, $B$, or $C$ but it could not be two out of those three right? If $A$ has order $4$ then $B$ and $C$ cannot be of order $4$ otherwise it will be redundant, the only thing you can say is that maybe what I use as $A^4 = I$ (of course what I mean here is $A$ has order $4$) is your $B^4 = I$ OR $C^4 = I$.

Comment: Re: your first comment, it's not your fault--Zee is being mathematically imprecise.  Whenever $A^2 = I$ in any group (e.g. $Z_2 \times Z_2$), it follows that $A^4 = I$--simply because $A^4 = A^2 \cdot A^2$.  Zee is using the statements "$A^2 = I$" and "$A^4 = I$" to mean "$ord(A) = 2$" and "$ord(A) = 4$", which are mutually exclusive.  To a mathematician, the two statements mean just what they say; they aren't mutually exclusive.    We reserve the word "order" for the *smallest* positive $n$ such that $A^n = I$.

Comment: Re: your second comment, if you look at your multiplication table for $Z_4$, you'll see that both $A$ and $C$ have order 4, while $B$ has order 2.  This is an example of a general fact:  a group element always has the same order as its inverse.  (Note that $A$ and $C$ are inverses because $AC = CA = I$.)  But I agree that it's redundant in some sense, since $A$ and $C$ are generating the same cyclic group.

Comment: I think I finally understood it. A quick way to construct the group table is to construct the cyclic subgroups. Start with $A$ and keep multiplying it by itself and if we reach $A^4=I$ then $ord(A)=4$ for the reason of the cyclic construction (not because $A^4=I$ which is just part of the process of cyclic construction and part of the confusion above). This property corresponds to a group named $Z_4$.

Comment: Now, if multiplying $A$ by itself we reached $A^2 = I$ then we say $ord(A)=2$; next we check $B$ (it could be $C$ but again renaming will fix this), where there are two possibilities, $B^2=I$ or $B^4=I$. I think saying $B^4=I$ is ruled out is not wrong but careless in wording, I think what Zee should have said is that we start by multiplying $B$ by itself and if we reach $B^2=I$ then $ord(B)=2$ and $B^4=I$ is just a consequence of $B^2B^2=I$, another is that if we multiply and reach $B^4=I$, we just go back to the group $Z_4$ which was already considered.

Comment: @WillOrrick I think it is in this sense we can "ignore" (we use this word instead of rule out) $B^4=I$ and consider only $B^2=I$ since this is what gives us the order of $B$ and which is what we set out to construct in order to define the corresponding group, i.e. for $Z_4$ we have $Z_4 = \{A|ord(A)=4\}$ and for $Z_2 \otimes Z_2$ we have $Z_2 \otimes Z_2 = \{A,B|ord(A)=ord(B)=2, AB=BA\}$ although in Zee's book he stated it as $Z_4 = \{A|A^4=I\}$ and $Z_2 \otimes Z_2 = \{A,B|A^2=B^2=I, AB=BA\}$ which is what causes the confusion. What do you think?

Comment: I agree it is plausible that Zee meant to say that the case $\operatorname{ord}(B)=4$ could be disregarded as equivalent to a case already considered. I'm glad to hear you have reached an understanding.

Comment: Be careful with your notation for groups. When you write $Z_4=\{A|\operatorname{ord}(A)\}$ I think you mean to use the notation of [group presentations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group), in which case you should write $Z_4=\langle A\vert A^4=I\rangle$. It is okay to write $A^4=I$ here because it is implicit in this notation that the only relations that hold are those that are explicitly stated or that follow from those. Note that angle brackets are required because you mean that $A$ generates the group. When you use curly brackets, you imply that $A$ is the only element.

Comment: @WillOrrick I will note all your comments regarding notations! So, I think everything has been cleared up. Thanks for your help!